# UITableViewCell UILabel non-english causes scrolling to stutter

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unicode, uilabel

I've got a UITableViewCell with a few UILabel instances in it that hold English or Thai text. When a cell with a UILabel with Thai text is displayed the tableview's scrolling will pause for a brief moment before continuing.

There are two cell prototypes and they are both designed using IB.

I've managed to narrow the stutter down to Thai-based text being the cause by removing any Thai from the output and then the view will scroll normally without any pause.

I've tried to reduce the total amount of text being set on the UILabel so that it *just* exceeds the UILabel limits and produces the required trailing "..." to show more text is available but that didn't really make much difference.

I've also commented out all sections of the method *except* the setText on the cell.msg label and it still stutters so I know it's not related to images etc (they are loading async anyway).

Could anyone with a bit more iOS dev experience than me point me in the correct direction for a fix on this?

Code for my table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"gettin cell: %@", indexPath);
    irrelonFeedTableViewCell *cell;
    NSDictionary *feedItem;
    NSString *postType;

    int replyCount = 0;
    BOOL hasGallery;
    BOOL hasReplyArray;

    // Get feed item by index
    feedItem = [self.feedItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Determine if the item has a gallery
    hasGallery = [[feedItem objectForKey:@"gallery"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]];
    hasReplyArray = [[feedItem objectForKey:@"replies"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]];

    if (hasReplyArray) {
        replyCount = [[feedItem objectForKey:@"replies"] count];
    }

    if (hasGallery) {
        cell = (irrelonFeedTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellGallery forIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        cell = (irrelonFeedTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellNoGallery forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    // Clear previous images from memory
    cell.authorImg.image = nil;
    cell.galleryImg1.image = nil;
    cell.galleryImg2.image = nil;
    cell.galleryImg3.image = nil;

    // Configure the cell...
    [cell.authorName setText:[[feedItem objectForKey:@"authorName"] uppercaseString]];

    if ([feedItem objectForKey:@"msgShort"]) {
        [cell.msg setText:[feedItem objectForKey:@"msgShort"]];
    } else {
        [cell.msg setText:[feedItem objectForKey:@"msg"]];
    }
    //[cell.msg alignTop];
    [cell.distance setText:@"1 MILE"];
    [cell.location setText:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", [[[feedItem objectForKey:@"geoPlace"] objectForKey:@"place"] uppercaseString], [[[feedItem objectForKey:@"geoPlace"] objectForKey:@"country"] uppercaseString]]];
    [cell.replyCount setText:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i REPLIES", replyCount]];

    // Assign the correct label to the type of post
    postType = [feedItem objectForKey:@"type"];
    if ([postType  isEqual: @"sale"]) {
        [cell.type setText:@"FOR SALE"];
        [cell.typeImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"status_green.png"]];
    } else if ([postType  isEqual: @"wanted"]) {
        [cell.type setText:@"WANTED"];
        [cell.typeImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"status_purple.png"]];
    } else if ([postType  isEqual: @"discuss"]) {
        [cell.type setText:@"DISCUSSION"];
        [cell.typeImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"status_blue.png"]];
    }

    // Set profile image async
    [cell.authorImg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[feedItem objectForKey:@"authorImg"]]];

    // Add gallery images
    if (hasGallery) {
        NSArray *gallery = [feedItem objectForKey:@"gallery"];
        int count = [gallery count];

        if (count > 0) {
            NSDictionary *galleryImgObj = (NSDictionary *) [gallery objectAtIndex:0];

            [cell.galleryImg1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@=s200-c", [galleryImgObj objectForKey:@"url"]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profilePlaceholder"]];
        }

        if (count > 1) {
            NSDictionary *galleryImgObj = (NSDictionary *) [gallery objectAtIndex:1];

            [cell.galleryImg2 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@=s200-c", [galleryImgObj objectForKey:@"url"]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profilePlaceholder"]];
        }

        if (count > 2) {
            NSDictionary *galleryImgObj = (NSDictionary *) [gallery objectAtIndex:2];

            [cell.galleryImg3 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@=s200-c", [galleryImgObj objectForKey:@"url"]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profilePlaceholder"]];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Would this have anything to do with fonts / fallback to Thai font at all? I'm currently using Helvetica Neue

Here is the offending label's settings:

[image: Label Settings]

Comment: It would help to see relevant code.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, had to switch computers (was writing on my PC) and you beat me to the edit! :)

Comment: does it stutter every time or just first time when it loads such cell?

Comment: @sha The NSLog at the top fires for each requested cell and if I watch the console output the cell with the Thai language entry is where the stutter occurs during the call to cellForRowAtIndexPath. When I profiled it the time profile showed 76% of the time was spent on the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier call.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense though... dequeueing should not change based on the language/font. Which label contains Thai text?

Comment: @sha It's the "msg" one: [cell.msg setText:[feedItem objectForKey:@"msgShort"]];

Comment: @sha I agree it doesn't make a lot of sense and I don't get why if I take out the thai text entry from the feed items it suddenly performs well. Also, literally commenting out that line with setText for the cell.msg also causes the performance to jump back to a normal speed.

Comment: Added an image with the current cell.msg UILabel settings from IB

Comment: Try to add a label with same thai text and same font. This should force OS to load special characters upfront. See if it makes any difference

Comment: @sha Hmm good idea, I'll give that a go now...

Comment: @sha I added the Thai text from the database (on that feed item) into the UILabel's value in IB and that did not affect the performance jitter unfortunately. I didn't adjust the font from it's current setting though. I'm not sure what font the Thai text would be displayed in. Is there any way to determine this at runtime maybe by NSLog'ing something?

Comment: @RobEvans: I'm not sure if there is a way... You can try to check ".font" property and dig down into specific font object.

Comment: @sha No luck. I googled and found the font "Thonburi" which has Thai glyphs and switched to that in the label but still has jitter... I'm just stumped now! NSLog(@"%@",[[cell.msg font] familyName]); gave the name of the font in use by the way.

Answer (score 0):

While building the dictionary app for thai-language.com (https://itunes.apple.com/app/thai-english-dictionary-from/id707246890), I encountered this sluggish scrolling issue as well.

At the time, I determined that it takes 3 conditions to trigger the problem:

1. labels have Thai text
2. font differs from the default
3. cell text labels have text that exceeds the available width (resulting in truncation and "...")

This leaves us with at least 3 workarounds:

1. avoid Thai text
2. avoid custom fonts
3. truncate the text yourself

You mention the latter yourself, and I suppose the former is not feasible, but you may want to give option #2 a shot and stick to the default (system) font for these labels. It worked for me.

On a side note, I went so far as to file a report on https://bugreport.apple.com/. My radar (15200211) was marked as a duplicate of 10535951, which appears to still be open.

Comment: Thanks buddy, this is worth a go, I will try #2 and let you know the result. I thought I was already using the default font but maybe not...

Comment: Using custom fonts did not solve it for me. I am guessing it is an iOS bug. Thanks for trying to help solve though!